# Font Awesome5 with input placeholder

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to add FontAwesome icon to input placeholder.

So I tried to write code like this.

[html]

`<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF167;"/>`

[css]

`font-family:'Font Awesome 5 Brands' !important`

It works fine. Youtube icon is in the input tag.

[image]

But When I add search icon(`placeholder="&#xF002;"`) into the placeholder, It doesn't work properly.

[image]

What is the problem of my code?

Font awesome cheatsheet is here -> https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `font-family` correct for that icon? Search might fall under a more general category, and not brands.

Comment: @sol It is a solid, so I fixed to Solid and Free, but it still doens't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `font-family` as below, but also set the `font-weight` according to which style you want to load. For Solid, the `font-weight` would be `900`.

```
input {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

[Here's a working CodePen to demonstrate.](https://codepen.io/fontawesome/pen/deBxBp)

This does require that you're properly loading Font Awesome 5, and it will only work in the [Webfonts with CSS method](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css). In the CodePen example, only Font Awesome Free Solid is being loaded.

[Here's a reference](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/web-fonts-with-css#styles-and-prefixes) showing the font weights associated with each Font Awesome style.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome 5 splits the icons into different families.

There's Solid, Brands and Regular. The search icon is a Solid or Regular style font. So you need to use `font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free;`

Comment: How are you loading Font Awesome?

Answer (score 0):

You can load all the fontawesome libraries with:

````
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384- 
50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" 
crossorigin="anonymous">```
````